# Create Class object through class name in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to Salesforce and want to code one requirement, I have an api name in string variable through which I want to create an object of that class.

For Eg. Object name is Account which is stored in string variable.
String var = 'Account'

Now I want to create object of 'Account'. In java it is possible by Class.forName('Account') but similar approach is not working in Salesforce Apex.

Can anyone please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) class. The documentation for it isn't terribly intuitive, perhaps you'll benefit more from the article that introduced it: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/dynamic-apex-class-instantiation-in-summer-12.html

I'm using this in managed package code which inserts Chatter posts (feed items) only if the org has Chatter enabled:

```
sObject fItem = (sObject)System.Type.forName('FeedItem').newInstance();
fItem.put('ParentId', UserInfo.getUserId());
fItem.put('Body', 'Bla bla bla');
insert fItem;
```

(If I'd hardcode the `FeedItem` class & insert it directly it'd mark my package as "requires Chatter to run").

Alternative would be to build a JSON representation of your object (String with not only the type but also some field values). You could have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171926/how-to-deserialize-json-to-sobject

At the very least now you know what keywords & examples to search for :)

---

**Edit:**

Based on your code snippet - try something like this:

```java
String typeName = 'List<Account>';
String content = '[{"attributes":{"type":"Account"},"Name":"Some account"},{"attributes":{"type":"Account"},"Name":"Another account"}]';

Type t = Type.forName(typeName);
List<sObject> parsed = (List<sObject>) JSON.deserialize(content, t);

System.debug(parsed);
System.debug(parsed[1].get('Name'));

// And if you need to write code "if it's accounts then do something special with them":
if(t == List<Account>.class){
    List<Account> accs = (List<Account>) parsed;
    accs[1].BillingCountry = 'USA';
}
```

Comment: `String objectName = i.Name;    // i.Name gives Object API name

//Below is the recommended line of code
 sObject fItem = (sObject)System.Type.forName(objectName).newInstance();

//Below line is giving me error of invalid type fItem
List<fItem> s = (List<fItem>) parser.readValueAs(List<fItem>.class);

// Below commented line is for one object and I am trying to do similar for multiple objects
// acc = (List<Account>) parser.readValueAs(List<Account>.class);

//At the end I am inserting that object
insert acc;`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the detailed info. I tried above info and coded but throwing invalid type still, might be because compiler needs type of object at the time of compilation only. Above is the exact code snippet which is failing

Comment: Thanks @eyescream, I got understanding on the explanation you gave but after modification and debugging it seems the issue is with JSON parsing. I am creating a new thread with details and will ping the link here, if you get time please have a look and suggest for the modifications. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Below is the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811763/facing-issue-in-creating-dynamic-objects-from-json