# Facing issue in creating dynamic objects from JSON

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

I am working on the requirement where a User can fetch the data from production box and insert it into developer sandbox by just giving production URL and creds. I am able to fetch data but somehow not able to convert the JSON to required object type. As I am newbie in Salesforce please don't mind for basic questions.

Below is the working logic and issue:

```
for(DataMigrationNAP__c d : dataMigrationNAP) // this loop will give all NAP object names and its corresponding fields like {'Account','Name,Phone,Id'},{'Opportunity', 'ID,Name, blah,blah'}...
{         
    final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v22.0/query/');
            String soql = 'Select '+d.NAPObjectFields__c+' From '+d.Name+' a limit ' + recordCount;
            theUrl.getParameters().put('q',soql);
            request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);
            String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);

            do{
                parser.nextToken();
            }while(parser.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(parser.getCurrentName()));
            parser.nextToken();

            String typeName = 'List<' + d.Name + '>';
            Type t  = Type.forName(typeName);
            List<sobject> acc1 = (List<sobject>) parser.readValueAs(t);
            insert acc1;
            System.debug('Values inserted : ' + acc1);
        }
```

Through above logic I am trying to fetch the data Object by Object and insert it into dev sandbox, I am able to fetch perfectly in JSON but not able to convert from JSON to required object. The issue is I can't hardcode Object or Type name because it will be a list of objects. Please let me know if you need any other detail and thanks in advance. Open for any other approach as well but it should be through apex coding only.

Comment: Why are you trying to deserialize soql request string   instead of body variable?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was trying something else, updating the code

Comment: @AlexPashkin Please have a look now, above code is working if I modify List<Accout> from List<sobject> in last third line , List<sobject> acc1 = (List<sobject>) parser.readValueAs(t);

Comment: probably better use upsert method instead of insert

Comment: yes @AlexPashkin that worked with upsert and small change of converting sobject to specific object before upsert. Thanks

Comment: Good to know. Just write the answer below and mark it as solving the issue.

Comment: Below code changes made it work

`String typeName = 'List<' + d.Name + '>';
                Type t  = Type.forName(typeName);
                acc1 = (List<sobject>) parser.readValueAs(t);
                List<SObject> castRecords = (List<SObject>)Type.forName(typeName).newInstance();
                castRecords.addAll(acc1);
                upsert castRecords;                
                System.debug('Values inserted : ' + acc1);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) already, if not than this could be good candidate.